# Plupload only working on MVC home

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, plupload

I have a bizarre problem with Plupload that I was hoping you could help me with.

I am using it with MVC and Amazon S3 and, taking the sample it all works fine.

So it is currently in the HomeController Index view.

Therefore if I navigate to localhost/ it works with no problems.

If I navigate to localhost/Home then the "Add File" button is not clickable due to the _Flash_Container being in the way.

Even if I use Firebug to get it out the way the "Add File" button doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have any idea?

My code is as follows:

```
@model MVC3PluploadToAmazonS3.ViewModels.FileUploadViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Upload to Amazon S3</h2>

<div id="uploader">
    <p>You browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus or HTML5 support.</p>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="key" value="@Model.FileId-${filename}">
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="@Model.PublicKey">
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="@Model.Acl">
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="@Model.RedirectUrl">
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="@Model.Policy">
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="@Model.Signature">

@section scriptFiles {
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#uploader").plupload({
        //amazon settings.
        runtimes: 'flash,silverlight',
        url: 'https://rapplex.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
        max_file_size: '100000000mb',
        multipart: true,
        multipart_params: {
            'key': '${filename}', // use filename as a key
            'Filename': '${filename}', // adding this to keep consistency across the runtimes
            'acl': $('#Acl').val(),
            'Content-Type': 'binary/octet-stream',
            'success_action_status': '201',
            'AWSAccessKeyId': $('#AWSAccessKeyId').val(),
            'policy': $('#Policy').val(),
            'signature': $('#Signature').val()
        },
        // optional, but better be specified directly
        //file_data_name: 'file',
        // re-use widget (not related to S3, but to Plupload UI Widget)
        //multiple_queues: true,

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        //resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
           // { title: "Video files", extensions: "mp4,m4v,wmv,avi,mov,mpg,mpeg,mkv" }
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
            //{ title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
        ],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: 'Scripts/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: 'Scripts/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });

});
</script>

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: OK some I have done some further investigating.

It seems that localhost/home does work but localhost/home/ and localhost/home/index do not work.

I have noticed that there are a bunch of @Import *.css in the initial css file and have changed them to be /path/to/file.css which doesnt make a difference. I also tried removing the first forward slash from the @imports but that just removed all of the styling so I know it's not that.

I also tried changing the .swf path to be absolute (localhost:2668/Scripts/plupload/plupload.flash.swf) but that also didn't work.

Comment: Does it also happen with localhost/Home/ (with a trailing /) ? Also was wondering if changing your flash_swf_url to an absolute path would change something

Comment: While investigating I have further info, including an answer to your first question. See my edit.

Comment: Try this absolute path instead `flash_swf_url: '/Scripts/plupload/plupload.flash.swf'`

Comment: Great! Thanks. That sorted it :)

Answer (score 0):

As phloopy pointed out, it was infact the path to the swf.

See the comments for the answer.

Thanks mate.